# Python list behavior causes me confusion

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, tuples

I'm coming from a JavaScript background and this might be why lists in Python feel a bit weird to me.
Can someone explain to me how this piece of code works and how i'm getting this to work the way i want?

```
a = [0,0]
b = a
a[0] = a[0]+1   #somehow manipulates b as well
print a         #i want this line to return [1,0]
print b         #i want this line to return [0,0], not [1,0]
```

I know there are lists and tuples (which are immutable), but this knowledge somehow didn't help me any further.

Help is appreciated. :)

Comment: Typical answer: the list is **not copied**: `a` and `b` **refer to the same list**. Use `b = list(a)` to copy the list.

Comment: `a` and `b` are names for objects. They name the same `list` object.

Comment: You've not made a copy with `b = a`, it's only creating a new label pointing to the same object. That's because the list is mutable. If `a = 3` (immutable int) then `b = a` would result in both pointing to separate `3` values.

To create a copy of a list use:
`b = a[:]`

Comment: @otocan: That explanation is wrong. `a = 3` and `b = a` still have them point to the same `3` value, it's just that being immutable, it doesn't matter that they refer to the same value; anything that changes them (e.g. `a += 1` will rebind `a` and leave `b` unchanged).

Comment: @ShadowRanger - thanks for the lesson. Leaving my comment up to give yours context.

Comment: @otocan I think it would be better to delete the comment as it's misleading, especially so since someone has upvoted it.